# Intuition behind eigenvalues of a graph mattering

Tags: graph-theory, matrices

Is there a good intuition behind why the eigenvalues of a matrix corresponding to a graph tell us useful information about the graph? There are a lot of results relating the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a graph to the graph, and similar statements about the eigenvalues of the Laplacian of the graph or the normalized Laplacian.

The best intuition I have is something like this: Given a graph $G$ with adjacency matrix $M$, one can imagine unicelled organisms on each vertex. At each stage, each organism reproduces and sends a copy of itself to each adjacent vertex. Then, given a given list $\vec{v}$ of initial numbers of organisms on each vertex, $M^k \vec{v}$ tells us how many are on each vertex after $k$ steps. A suitably normalized version of this then corresponds to the ratios of the populations at each vertex, and that connects with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

One can tell a somewhat similar story of random walks and the Laplacian.

But these seem very handwavy. Is there a better explanation for why the eigenvalues of these matrices are so useful?

Comment: The connection between walks and eigenvalues seems very direct to me.

Comment: @SamHopkins Maybe, but then the eigenvalues end up telling us information about things which have nothing to do with walks in any obvious way.  How for example does the Hoffman-Delsarte inequality fit into that thought process? It seems like a lot of results involving eigenvalues of the graph don't connect to much involving walks at all in any obvious way.

Comment: Sure, it seems that eigenvalues arise in various, unrelated ways. For example the Matrix Tree Theorem has nothing to do with walks (or taking powers of matrices, for that matter), as far as I can tell.

Comment: Perhaps the truth is mundane: graphs are inherently "two-dimensional" in a way similar to how matrices are (compare to hypergraphs vs. tensors); so there are naturally many ways of encoding a graph via a matrix; and we have developed many tools for understanding matrices, especially via their eigenvalues.